# Error al hacer sumas con decimales en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de sumar N valores con decimales con  javascript, el problema es que lo logra sumar:
ejemplo `53.113,20 + 12,50 = Unexpected number`

Tengo una función que convierte mis totales en formato moneda:

```
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
            var n = this, 
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
                i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))), 
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
            return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
         };
```

Ejemplo:

```
var x = 53113,20;
x.formatoMoneda(2, '.', ',');
var y = 12,50;
y.formatoMoneda(2, '.', ',');
```

El resultado sería esto:

```
x = 53.113,20;
y = 12,50
```

Al sumar `x+y = ERROR.`

Comment: **`,`** es un carácter reservado. utilizar **`.`** para los decimales

Comment: Pasa que lo estoy usando una funciona para volverlas a fomato moneda.

Comment: Agrega lo del formato a la pregunta, o bien publica una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Pero puedes aplicar el formato moneda, solo al momento de mostrar en el input la información, o en donde lo quieras mostrar, de resto, guárdalo normal, con su decimal de la forma clásica.

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez realiza la suma antes `x+y` y el resultado le aplicas el formato moneda , puede tomar en cuenta este formato. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16233919

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En JavaScript no existe el concepto de formatos de números, que es lo que estás haciendo al declarar dichos números. En JavaScript existe un único formato y es:

```
<parte entera>.<parte decimal>
```

Por ende, los números que declaras debes cambiarlos a:

```
var x = 53113.20;
var y = 12.50;
```

La coma literal, principalmente separa expresiones, por ejemplo:

```
var x = 53113.20,
    y = 12.50;
```

Al encontrar una coma, el motor *espera una declaración*; en este caso en específico, **espera una asignación** de un valor a una variable al estar dentro de una instrucción de declaración.

> Lo que pasa es que el son totales de productos y esas lo estoy pasando a una funcion que me convierte a formato moneda.

Eso **no aplica al trabajar con programación**. Ni a los lenguajes de programación, ni a las bases de datos les interesa tener obligatoriamente un formato de moneda (de los varios disponibles internacionalmente). Esos mismos números los puedes insertar en una base de datos sin problema alguno.

Un caso diferente para lo cual aplica lo que explicas, es cuando se quiere generar *ciertos archivos en donde se mantenga un formato de moneda*, como es el caso de una hoja de cálculo. En ese caso, te basta hacer una pequeña función para convertir un Number a una representación en texto de acuerdo a un formato en específico.

La libería [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) te permite formatear un número JavaScript a un formato específico. En tu caso, el formato debe ser `0,0.00`:

```js
const x = 53113.20;
const y = 12.50;

console.info(numeral(x + y).format('0,0.00'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el son totales de productos y esas lo estoy pasando a una funcion que me convierte a formato moneda...

Comment: @JhosselinGiménez He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Pero aun tengo un problema, esta se va a un value  y cuando hago la suma es con los values esta lo toma 1,00.32 así  jejeje

Comment: Cuando recuperes los valores, debes pasarlos nuevamente a número. Esto lo haces pasando el número formateado a la función `numeral`. Por ejemplo: `const x = numeral('53,113.20');`.

Comment: Tengo este codigo, la suma de los productos se realiza de esta manera: https://codepen.io/Jhoss/pen/gmNoeb

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en ese pen? Veo que la suma se hace correctamente.

Comment: Realiza la suma, pero cuando el total es 12,344,30 esta esta se satura y da otros valores.

Comment: Perdón, me falta el formato moneda en ese PEN... ¿Me ayudas?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56773/discussion-between-gustavo-garcia-and-jhosselin-gimenez).

Answer (score 0):

no se necesita la coma, para poder diferenciar si es entero o decimal, dividelos mediante el `.` punto

```js
var x = 53113.20;
var y = 12.50;
var total = x + y;

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Falta incluir una explicación de lo propuesto.

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

1. En JavaScript el separador de decimales es el punto
2. Las funciones para dar formato a los números devuelven cadenas (strings).

## Explicación

A continuación hago la explicación de lo indicado arriba, por partes, primero la asignación de números a variables y luego el uso de funciones nativas.

### Primera parte: Asignación de números a variables

En la guía de Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) sobre cómo trabajar con [números y fechas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates) no se indica explícitamente que el separador de decimales es el punto, sin embargo, al ver los ejemplos esto se puede identificar.

Entonces al asignar una número a una variable en JavaScript en lugar de

```
var x = 53113,20;
```

Lo correcto es

```
var x = 53113.20;
```

y en lugar de

```
var y = 12,50;
```

lo correcto es

```
var y = 12.50;
```

### Segunda parte: Formato de números

Lo que solemos llamar formato en la documentación sobre JavaScript de MDN le llama "representación del número acorde al idioma". Para esto JavaScript incluye de forma nativa dos funciones

- [Number.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString)
- [Intl.NumberFormat.format](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat)

La segunda se recomienda cuando se vayan a convertir grandes cantidades de número pues se desempeña mejor, según MDN.

Integrando lo anterior el código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```js
// Asignación de variables a número
var x = 53113.20;
var y = 12.50;

// suma
var suma = x + y;

// Formato
var options = {minimumFractionDigits:2} // Con esto aseguramos que se muestren 2 decimales como mínimo
console.info('x: ' + x.toLocaleString('es-ES',options));
console.info('y: ' + y.toLocaleString('es-ES',options));
console.info('suma: ' +suma.toLocaleString('es-ES',options));
```

Cabe hacer notar que las funciones anteriores tienen limitaciones en cuanto a su compatibilidad con navegadores, pero estas funcionan en los principales navegadores en sus versiones recientes, según tengo entendido. Cómo en la pregunta no se menciona navegadores objetivo se considera esto fuera del alcance de la discusión.